# How to do the new PlayStore parallax effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, material-design, android-scroll

Does anyone know how can I achieve the new parallax scrolling effect - you can see the effect when you open an app on the PlayStore and try to scroll down, the content goes over the top image. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: just 100 or so lines of code, see: http://gist.github.com/pskink/d7089e5a82c970917be1 and sample implementation: http://gist.github.com/pskink/d7f0673b77fe8537b270

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Google has recently announced [Design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and with this it has support for implementing **Collapsing Toolbar**.

> In addition to pinning a view, you can use
>   `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` (and optionally
>   `app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"` to set the parallax
>   multiplier) to implement parallax scrolling (say of a sibling
>   ImageView within the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`)

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This is the preferred way. No need for 3rd party!

Comment: @Paresh Mayani i have kind of similar problem, can you please take a look at it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760578/implement-globe-weis-file-folder-in-android   thanks

Answer (score 29):

<strike>You could try this (FadingActionBar library):
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar</strike>

Try an example of this library on android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.demo

**EDIT:** Rather than third party library use this AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 19):

try the **ObservableScrollView** library

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

demo application from play store

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.samples2

sample demo,

[image]

Comment: Why to suggest 3rd party library when Google has already announced [Design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)!

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks for info..But why downvote only for me?. all the answers are give 3rd party library including accepted answer..

Comment: Because you have posted answer after Google has already announced an official support library!

Comment: Material design library doesn't support fling gesture. Bad experience with scrollview! I'll try this library.

Comment: It`s any necessary we only use the official methods.. If better than official we can go for 3rd party..for ex Networking library **Retrofit** faster than official library.Then what is our choice?

Comment: Certainly an upvote because the cost of adding *official design support library* to the gradle dependency certainly equals the cost of adding 3rd party gradle dependency, sometimes with the added benefits of far greater support as mentioned by @wisemann

Answer (score 4):

There's a library called `FadingActionBar` that does exactly what you're asking for. You can find the library on [GitHub (click)](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) and a Demo-Application in the [Play Store (click)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.demo).

Usage would be something like this:

```
FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
    // Set the ActionBar drawable - basically the color
    .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
    // Set the Header - usually an image
    .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
    // Set the main layout
    .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_scrollview);
setContentView(helper.createView(this));
helper.initActionBar(this);
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually few minutes after posting this question I bumped on two of libraries that do the effect I'm looking for and even more.

Here are links to them:

- [Parallax Scrolls](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)
- [Paralloid](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid)

Answer (score 0):

You may custom the parallax animation by tracking the Recycler View Scrolling

Firstly in the image view layout. Set the parent layout is smaller than image view so that prevent the image outside the bound when set translationY

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/index_level6_image_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/index_level6_parallaxImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/timberwolf"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-20"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:imageUrl="@{level6CellViewModel.level6ImageUrl}" />

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

After that, track the recycler view scrolling effect and transitionY the image view.

*** I am using rxbinding and kotlin for implementation. You may use traditional listening method and java approach with the same idea.

```
RxRecyclerView.scrollEvents(recyclerView)
                    .subscribe { event ->
                        // get the visible cell items of the recycler view
                        val firstVisible = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                        val visibleCount = Math.abs(firstVisible - layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition())

                        /** loop the visible cell items from the recycler view */
                        for (i in firstVisible..firstVisible + visibleCount) {
                            event.view().layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(i)?.let { cellItem ->
                                /** only for index cell level 6 parallax image */
                                cellItem.findViewById(R.id.index_level6_parallaxImage)?.let { imageView ->
                                    /** setting the parallax effect */
                                    val translationY = (cellItem.top - cellItem.height) / level6ParallaxRate
                                    imageView.translationY = -translationY
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```