# Android: Creating an Item Fade Animation when Scrolling (Example Included)

Tags: java, android, mobile, imageview, android-animation

I've seen this specific animation in certain apps where when scrolled, the first item on the window (most commonly an ImageView) gets faded out when scrolling down. Here's two screenshots that display the animated change:

This is from a fashion app named "Polyvore":

[image]

> > The image above displays an ImageView which gets faded out when scrolled. Animated more like.
> >     **And after scrolling a bit..**

[image]

And it ultimately fades out along with the scrolling. Pardon me for I don't know what this 'View' or animation is called. I've seen this in the Google Play Music app as well. How do I implement this?

Comment: Are you looking for Alpha Animation?

Comment: Is that what it is? I googled Alpha Animation but I didn't see this 'specific' animation. Judging by the pictures, haven't you experienced an app which had this animation? @Whitney

Comment: You are going to have to combine them, however actually using an alpha animation could get tricky if the user goes up and down repeatedly. Instead you might want to see how far the user has scrolled up or down and adjust the alpha value based on that. There is no API solution that is scroll and fade that I know of.

Comment: @Whitney I found the answer here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461014/how-to-do-the-new-playstore-parallax-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this specific effect. It's known as a Parallax effect. Check this link:

[How to do the new PlayStore parallax effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461014/how-to-do-the-new-playstore-parallax-effect)